# Create a Spark Dataframe on Time

Tags: scala, apache-spark

quick question that I did not find on google.

What is the best way to create a Spark Dataframe with time stamps

lets say I have startpoint endpoint and a 15 min interval. What would be the best way to resolve this on spark ?

Comment: As much as I'd like to help, I'd also want to understand your question. It's not clear to me ! Please review it and maybe add an example to illustrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try SparkSQL inside udf like this `DF.withColumn("regTime",current_timestamp)` ,it's can replace a column ,
you also can convert a String to date or timestamp use `DF.withColumn("regTime", to_date(spark_temp_user_day("dateTime")))`
regTime is a column of DF

Comment: not exactly  what I'm looking for. but thanks any way